# PHP division precision

Tags: php

I'm doing this division :

```
$a = 26.25;
$result = $a / 100; // Result : 0.26
```

How can I have a float number with more precision ? The result I want is 0.2625, not 0.26.

Thank you.

Comment: This code gives me `0.2625`

Comment: https://3v4l.org/err43 Works for me.

Comment: The result depend on the php configuration, so it's normal to work in certain case or not in other, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you want every division with the same precision** :

You can modify the precision using :

```
ini_set('precision', 4); // your precision
```

Or modify your **php.ini** to set precision value to whatever you want.

However, as @vivek_23 precised, if you want to do this only **for one operation** using [number_format](https://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
$a = 26.25;
$result = $a / 100; // Result : 0.26

echo number_format($result, 4);
```

Comment: Better to use [number_format](https://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)